# How to load external config file for pagination in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I've been on the `Codeigniter`'s documentation and I want to have an external configuration file for pagination, so I did the following:

I put my `$config` array in `config/pagination.php` and then on every controller I need to use the configuration file for the pagination I'll use:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
$config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
$config['per_page'] = $per_page;
$pag_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

I thought that was all. The problem is that it doesn't work. I searched for this on the site and found these two questions already answered: [How to change data in custom loaded config array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706828/how-to-change-data-in-custom-loaded-config-array) and [autoload config for pagination in codeigniter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316428/autoload-config-for-pagination-in-codeigniter-not-working)

They both suggested the following line of code:

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

But Codeigniter's documentation says:

> Setting preferences in a config file
>
> If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can
>   instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called
>   pagination.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file
>   in application/config/pagination.php and it will be used
>   automatically. You will NOT need to use
>   $this->pagination->initialize() if you save your preferences in a
>   config file.

Well, The important part is **You will NOT need to use $this->pagination->initialize() if you save your preferences in a config file.**

Of course, If I put that line of code in my own code it works.

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
$config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
$config['per_page'] = $per_page;
$pagination->initialize($config);
$pag_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Am I missing something important here? **What's the right way to create an external configuration file for Codeigniter's pagination?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config array should be stored at application/config/pagination.php
You then do not need to add:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
$config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
$config['per_page'] = $per_page;
```

in the controller only call the library

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
```

as the config you created have these in there...
only thing I can think of if is you are using the variables $total_rows, etc in the config file to be automagically loaded as these would not be referencing anything in an external file... You would need to specify the values directly, e.g.:

```
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
```

however, if those values need to be specified inside the controller, you would need to use the way you have said and use the

```
$pagination->initialize($config);
```

in the controller.